# Why is returning 1 required in this Postgres code block?

Tags: postgresql, postgres15

Asking this question for a colleague who ran into this behaviour with PostgreSQL. Hoping somebody out there can solve this puzzle for us.

The following logs `Rows updated: 3` when run:

```sql
drop table if exists test;
create table test (str text);

insert into test(str)
values ('row1'), ('row2'), ('row3');

do $$
declare
    _row_count bigint = -1;
begin

    prepare update_test as
        update test
        set str = str
        where true
        returning 1; -- why is this needed?

    execute 'execute update_test';
    get diagnostics _row_count := row_count;

    deallocate update_test;

    raise notice 'Rows updated: %', _row_count;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

However, the `returning 1` line should not be necessary, as we're looking at the rows count diagnostic. Indeed, running the contents of the anonymous code block directly logs 3 even with the `returning 1` removed.

But running the whole thing with the `returning 1` removed logs a value of zero, not the expected 3.

---

Update:

The example above is a simplication of the problem. What we're actually trying to achieve here is a general purpose procedure that can run a variety of named prepared statements. As such, the dynamic call is necessary.

Here is a bigger example of what we're trying to achieve:

```sql
-- general purpose procedure
drop procedure if exists run_sql(text);
create procedure run_sql(named_statement text)
as $$
declare
    _row_count bigint = -1;
begin
    -- do some stuff

    execute 'execute ' || named_statement;
    get diagnostics _row_count := row_count;

    raise notice 'Rows updated: %', _row_count;

    -- do some other stuff
end
$$ language plpgsql;

-- example usage
prepare update_test as
        update test
        set str = str
        where true
        returning 1; -- why is this needed?
call run_sql('update_test');
deallocate update_test;
```

So we cannot simplify the code in the procedure to call execute directly: it has to be a dynamic call. But it would be good if the passed in statements did not have to have `returning 1` on the end.

Comment: I'm betting it is the  `execute 'execute ...`. From here [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN): *...The server's EXECUTE statement cannot be used directly within PL/pgSQL functions (and is not needed).*.  The `plpgsql` `EXECUTE` does the same thing(basically) as the SQL `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment. `execute 'execute ...` is redundant so simplify to:

```
do $$
declare
    _row_count bigint = -1;
begin

    execute  'update test
        set str = str
        where true';

    get diagnostics _row_count := row_count;


    raise notice 'Rows updated: %', _row_count;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

NOTICE:  Rows updated: 3
DO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Adrian. I have updated the question to provider a full example of why we cannot make your suggested change. Any other ideas on how to get the row count to be correctly returned in this general case would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't how the general example can be made to work without the `returning`. The inner `execute` needs to actually `return` a value for the outer `execute` to  count. The only other option I can think of is not to pass in the prepared statement name, but to to pass in the query as text and use that with the `plpgsql execute` alone.

Answer (score 0):

The construction is rather strange as well: The plpgsql statement `EXECUTE` doesn't cache the query plan. And because of this you use `PREPARE` to create a query plan that can be repeated. Caching the query plan is the only thing that could have some value in here, anything to avoid SQL injection can be done by placeholders in plpgsql or `format()` in combination with plpgsql's `EXECUTE`.

And if you would use a plain `UPDATE` in your code, the plan would have been cached by default. Using less code and simpler code would result in the same functionality: Secure and fast code.

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        _row_count BIGINT;
    BEGIN
        UPDATE test
        SET str = str
        WHERE TRUE;

        GET DIAGNOSTICS _row_count := ROW_COUNT;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Rows updated: %', _row_count;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Rows updated: 3